# Шифровальщик на Python, расшифровывающий данные, когда вставлен USB ключ

Tags: python, linux

1. Возможно ли такое сделать на python, под Linux?
2. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: да, возможно. Для начала нужен usb ключ с его апи.

Answer (score 1):

1. Возможно
2. Зависит от драйвера ключа и от поддерживаемых им стандартов.

В общем случае когда говорит о ключах на токенах в линуксе стоит начать изучение с pkcs11. Установите демон `pcscd`, попробуйте прочитать сертификат с ключа через `pcsc-tools`. Если всё получится, то уже занимайтесь питоном. Первая попавшаяся для этого библиотека [python-pkcs11](http://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .